# Why isn't my code returning a full list of members in a discord server?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have been trying to print a list of all users inside a discord server using guild.members. I have activated `SERVER MEMBERS INTENT`, `PRESENCE INTENT`, and `MESSAGE CONTENT INTENT`, however the command still fails.

I have no idea why it isn't working but here is a copy of the error message:

```text
File "main.py", line 220, in getMemberList
    membersList = guild.members
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'members'
```

Here is a thorough copy of the code:

```python
# Import discord.py. Allows access to Discord's API. Also set up intents and guild.
import discord
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.messages = True
intents.guilds = True
intents.members = True
intents.presences = True

# random unrelated code here

# Creates a new Bot object with a specified prefix.
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$", intents = intents)

guild = bot.get_guild(guildID)

# random unrelated code here

@bot.command()

async def getMemberList(ctx):
  membersList = guild.members
  print(membersList)
```

Comment: It appears that `bot.get_guild(guildID)` did not find any matching guild, so it returned `None`.

Comment: @JohnGordon Yeah, you are right. I tested it with this code: `async def checkGuildID(ctx):
  print(guild)` and it returned none. Any clue on how I might go on about fixing this issue?

Comment: What is `guildID`?

Comment: It is the server ID of my personal discord server. It's not actually listed as guildID in the code, but the actual numbers themselves.

Comment: In your code, what is the type of `guildID`?  Is it an integer or a string?

Comment: Put the `bot.get_guild` inside the command... It gets the guild from cache, if it's outside the function, the cache is not loaded because the bot isn't running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few things to keep in mind:

- Please don't mix upper- and lowercase characters. Commands should always be in lowercase.
- As Łukasz Kwieciński pointed out correctly: Put `bot.get_guild` inside your command, otherwise you might run into problems when accessing the guild and cache
- The `guildID` “variable”, whether it is defined, has to be an integer

**Here's a revised code:**

```py
@bot.command()
async def getmemberlist(ctx: commands.Context):
     guild = bot.get_guild(YourGuildID)  # Or you can just use ctx.guild
     members = [member.name for member in guild.members]
     print(', '.join(members))
```

Please note that you can also use a different approach, such as a for-loop with more lines and a different output.

Comment: This worked, sorry for the late response and shitty question formatting. Thanks goat.

Answer (score -1):

For a member list do this:

```
@bot.command()
async def getMemberList(ctx:commands.Context):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    guild = ctx.guild
    for member in guild.members:
        print(member)
```

also import this: `from discord.ext import commands`